# SQL Server - Product and their latest information required from history table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ranking

I have a `Products` table with following columns

```
ProductId - INT - PK
Name - Varchar
Price Decimal
```

I have another table `ProductPriceHistory`

When Product Price is updated, using a trigger, I store old and new prices in that table. This table has following columns

```
ProductPriceHistoryId
Name
OldPrice
NewPrice
UpdateDate
```

I can join this table based on the `Name` columns.

Now question is, in my result set - I want to get `Product.Name`, `Product.Price` and (for getting the last updated value in table `ProductPriceHistory` ) `ProductPriceHistory.NewPrice`.

Challenge is that in history table, I have lots of rows for each product based on differet dates. For each product, I need to get the information from the latest row stored for this product.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the ProductId on the history table because it's unique, then join the tables on that value.

Then, order your query by date descending, limit 1 (or Select Top 1 fields From...). That will give you the latest update only.

Edit: Your table structure isn't normalized. It would make more sense to me for your tables to be:

```
Products:
ProductId
Name
Description

Prices:
ProductId
Price
UpdateDate
```

Then your query would be:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 Products.ProductId, Products.Name, Prices.Price, Prices.UpdateDate FROM etc
```

Comment: Limiting the nubmer of rows a query returns is not standard sql, its availability depends on the dbms.

Comment: Edited to include "Select Top..."

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL way of doing that is joining the historic table with an aggregation of itself, in which for each product you take the maximum date.

```
select  t1.Name, t1.Price, t2.NewPrice
from    Products t1
join    ProductPriceHistory t2
on      t1.Name = t2.name
join    (
          select  Name, max(UpdateDate) as MaxDate
          from    ProductPriceHistory
          group by Name
        ) t3
on      t2.Name = t3.Name and t2.UpdateDate = t3.MaxDate
```